# How do I render only a substring of a field as json in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to render only the first three letters of the `first_name` field and the last three letters of the `email` field in the `Nominee`model as json:

```
  def list
    render json:  Nominee.all, only: [:id, :first_name, :email, :phone,]
  end
```

Where `Nominee.all` is the array of customers, and `first_name`, `email`, and `phone` are fields of the type `string` in the Nominee model.

How can I do this?

Comment: [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) seems to be a good fit here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a method for the last three letters of email to your Model:

```
class Nominee < ActiveRecord::Base # Or ApplicationRecord
  def last_three_of_email
    ...
  end
end
```

Use the `:methods` options of `to_json`:

```
nominee.to_json(
  only: [:id, :first_name, :email, :phone], 
  methods: [:last_three_of_email]
)
```

Send back the desired JSON to the client:

```
render json: Nominee.all.to_json(...)
```

If this gets any more complex then I suggest you look into the Serializers (see comment by Sergio Tulentsev) or JBuilder for rendering custom JSON.